# mysql functions for days as expected and then gives 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have LAMP setup running on ubuntu. I am using this setup to run torrentflux with a web interface that requires mysql.

All works as expected for a few days, and then I get 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)'

I rebooted to fix the problem, but now the inconvenience of doing so has surpassed the reward of solving the problem, and I would like to find another way to solve the problem.

Mysql is the only failure in the LAMP setup for torrentflux. Torrentflux still leeches and seeds as it should; I simply lose the control interface without mysql. Apache still does its thing as expected.

Yes, mysql is running until the error is output when I try to use the web interface, and then it is impossible to restart the mysql server.

```
$ sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start
```

Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

G/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
130126 14:42:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130126 14:42:15 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130126 14:42:15 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130126 14:42:15 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
130126 14:42:16 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
130126 14:42:16 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130126 14:42:16 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
130126 14:42:16 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
130126 14:42:16 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
130126 14:42:16 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
130126 14:42:16 [ERROR] Aborting
```

mysql was running until I shut it down.

Rebooting fixes the problem for a while. I wish for a less drastic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You changed your question around a bit, so moved the old answer down below.

Either way, what you're getting in the log is fairly clear;

```
130126 14:42:16 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
130126 14:42:16 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

`errno 12` means you're out of memory. MySQL tries to allocate 128MB for the buffer pool, but can't find that much free memory.

I'm not sure what kind of machine you're running on, but you basically have 3 options;

- Find whichever application is hogging memory and see if you can update or swap it out.
- Get more memory for the machine (probably the best option if the first fails)
- Add some swap space (may slow things down quite a bit)

---

Old answer before edit;

You're getting that message because you're trying to start MySQL as your normal user, not as root as required.

Try;

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: You are correct. However, using sudo didn't solve this issue. I edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: @user1913726 Have a look at `sudo less /var/log/upstart/mysql.log`, it may give you some clue as to why upstart fails.

Comment: Added the output from the log file. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you for the translation of the error log and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your my.ini:

```
[mysqld] 
innodb=OFF 
ignore-builtin-innodb 
skip-innodb
default-storage-engine=myisam 
default-tmp-storage-engine=myisam
```

it worked for me :)